# Python average of 3 numbers calculation

Tags: python, average

for some reason, my calculation is not coming out correct. All I'm trying to do is find the average of 3 numbers that a user inputs. Here's def that it sits in, if more is needed, just ask.

```
#===================== Calculates the average of all three ==========================

def calc_average(self): #average calculation
    stop_one_mileage = self.__route[0].stop_one_mileage #stop_one_mileage average
    stop_two_mileage = self.__route[0].stop_two_mileage #stop_two_mileage
    stop_three_mileage = self.__route[0].stop_three_mileage #stop_three_mileage
    avg = int(stop_one_mileage) + int(stop_two_mileage) + int(stop_three_mileage)/3 #adds all three and divides by three
    return "<div class='results-container'><span class='title'>Average Mileage: </span><span class='results-container'>" + str(avg) + " miles</span></div>" #returns results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
avg = int(stop_one_mileage) + int(stop_two_mileage) + int(stop_three_mileage)/3
```

Change it to:

```
avg = (int(stop_one_mileage) + int(stop_two_mileage) + int(stop_three_mileage))/3
```

Because this is what's happening:

```
>>> 2 + 2 + 2 / 3
4
>>> (2 + 2 + 2) / 3
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps did you forget to use parenthesis?

```
avg = (int(stop_one_mileage) + int(stop_two_mileage) + int(stop_three_mileage))/3
```

Otherwise it will divide only the last number by 3 then it will sum the others. Take a look at [Python operator precedence documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Comment: Yes! Of course it was something stupid like that! It's always something small like that. Thank you so much Pablo, you're the man!